# Does LSD "stay" in your fat storage and then "returns" back?

Tags: pharmacology, human-physiology, fat-metabolism, pharmacokinetics

This rumor was told me by a very anti-drug person. A stance I agree with only lightly.

The rumor was that when you take LSD, it stores itself in your fat storage, and then returns back in 3-6 months, returning back meaning there would be another series of effects of LSD (the trip).

Is this true? I highly doubt it. However, what I don't know, if the body is processing (burning?) fat *and then* processing substances (such as the rumoured LSD) found in fat stores.

Comment: Welcome to SE.biology. I downvoted because questions based on rumours from other people don't tend to encourage speculative and non-evidence based answers. Take a read of the [help-centre](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help) to find advice on how to ask a good question. Thanks!

Comment: @user438383 This is actually a very widely-spread idea (with several variations) amongst the drug and hallucinogenic community. The version I've heard most is that it accumulates in CSF or just "the spine", however as I reference in my answer, it's not true.

Comment: @user438383 I haven't found much evidence on the web about this, so I had to ask here.

Comment: @TimotejLeginus showing a little research would probably keep your question from being closed. Alternatively you may want to drop this question the skeptic stack, urban legends like this area better fit there. I know a lot of scientists who believe this urban legend, until today myself included, so it deserves a little attention.

Comment: @John kind of interesting that sciencists believe these things too! I would have done some research, but before this, I would be unsure where to start, now I would be sure where to :p

Comment: @TimotejLeginus a scientist outside their specialty is not much better than a layman, and paleontology does not involve much pharmacology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've heard this rumor for years, both from pro- and anti-drug people, and it is not true. According to [this review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6494066/) of LSD's pharmacology, its half-life in the body is about 5 hours, with it being completely cleared within about 15-28 hours. There is no evidence that it accumulates long-term in fat, cerebrospinal fluid (CSF), or anywhere else in any pharmacologically significant quantity.

Reference:
"The Pharmacology of Lysergic Acid Diethylamide: A Review" *CNS Neurosci Ther.* 2008 Winter; 14(4): 295–314. PMID: [19040555](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19040555) DOI: [10.1111/j.1755-5949.2008.00059.x](https://dx.doi.org/10.1111%2Fj.1755-5949.2008.00059.x)

Comment: My guess is that flashbacks are almost or entirely psychological, where the brain and the rest of the CNS somehow gets triggered in a similar way that acid does. Also, hallucinations can occur in a number of severe psychiatric diseases, independently of past drug use, so that likely has a role, too.